# How may occupied positions are there?

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity

Consider an array, that can have a huge ( or infinite ) number of positions, but only the first $n$ positions are occupied(only $n$ of them contain valid elements), and the remaining are empty. Consider that, for us, $n$ is unknown.

A program has been constructed that can answer questions about the number of occupied positions of the array. The program gives only answers of the form YES or NO. So, the questions that we ask should have a suitable form, so that an answer of the form  YES or NO makes sense( for example: has the array more than 100 occupied positions?).

Describe what kind of questions you would ask the program and in which order, so that you determine the exact number of occupied positions of the array, i.e to find $n$. It is not allowed to ask more than $O(\log n)$ questions.

How can we ask $O(\log n)$ suitable questions to find an upper bound and how can we find, then, the exact number of occupied positions of the array?

**EDIT**: That's what I have tried:

```
 Positions()
    {
      int pos=1, low=2, high;
      char answer;
      printf("Is the number of occupied positions equal to 1? \n");
      scanf("%c",&answer);
      if (answer=='YES'){
         printf("1 position is occupied.\n");
         return;
      }
      answer='NO';
      while (answer=='NO'){
             pos=2*i;
             printf("Is the number of occupied positions  <= %d ? \n",pos);
             scanf("%c",&answer);
        }
        high=pos;
        return BinarySearch(low, high);
    }
```

And the BinarySearch that we use is the following:

```
 BinarySeach(low,high){
       int mid=low+floor((high-low)/2);
       char answer;
       printf("Is the number of occupied positions equal to %d", mid);
       if (answer=='YES') return mid;
       else{
            printf("Is the number of occupied positions <= %d", mid);
            if (answer=='YES')  BinarySeach(low,mid-1);
            else BinarySeach(mid+1,high);
       }
    }
```

Is it right? If so, how could it be justified that the time complexity of the algorithm `Positions()` is equal to O(logn)?

Comment: You have had a couple of answers. Anything to say about them?

Answer (score 1):

You're basically looking for a series of questions that resemble a binary search. Binary search runs average O($\log n$) and worst O($\log n$).

Questions like, "is position n occupied", should suffice. Make sure each subsequent question tries to cut the problem size in half.

**Note:** Try asking for an extremely large value, if yes, double the value size, if no, reduce the value size by half and ask again.

Comment: So, is this the only way, to assume at the beginning an upper bound, in order to find the right upper bound, using binary search?

Comment: Pretty much, because you don't know "what size" the array could be. What your trying to track down is the maximal number. So start with a really high guess (since this is a theoretical problem. In a real world you could use a heuristic to guess at what that maximal number should be around). And to do anything other wouldn't necessarily make the algorithm less efficient.. You could guess for a smaller large number, or a small number, because you are protected by the binary search worst case run time guarantee- making a bad choice at first only effects your run time, not the big oh.

Comment: To be concise: Having a bad first guess doesn't change the asymptotic time complexity guarantee of the big oh analysis. A bad first guess shows up as a constant in the analysis and will eventually get dropped when the big oh is finalized; however, constant subsequent bad guesses may mean that you are not following a binary search algorithm and therefore no complexity guarantee can be made for that case.

Comment: I edited my post and added an algorithm.. Could you take a look at it? And could you maybe explain me why the time complexity of Positions() is equal to $O(\log n)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

First ask "Is 1 occupied?", then, "Is 2 occupied?", "Is 4 occupied?", "Is 8 occupied?", and so on, until you get the answer, "no". This will take $\log_2n$ questions (give or take a fraction).

You now know $k$ such that $n$ is between $2^k$ and $2^{k+1}$, and binary search inside that interval will get you the answer in another $\log_2n$ questions.

Comment: So, do we have to ask about all the positions if they are occupied or not?

Comment: Asking about all positions would imply a linear search algorithm. This simply is a (K+1)+$\log_2n$ algorithm where the K+1 searches are simply a constant and will be factored out of the complexity analysis. You will eventually have the range to implement the binary search on.

Comment: The run time on this is quick for smaller arrays, but lengthens if the arrays are substantially large (near infinite sizes). So if you have any reason in the real world to suspect a large array value, start with the top down approach. If the array might me small or mediocre in size, use this bottom up approach.

Comment: Why, evinda, do you think you have to ask about all positions? You ask about 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, and so on, and so on, until you get a "no". Suppose that happens at 128. Then you know $n$ is somewhere between 64 and 127. So you ask about 96. If the answer is yes, you ask about 112; if no, 80. And so on. If $n$ is about $2^r$, you ask about $2r$ questions.

Comment: So, are you OK now?

Comment: I edited my post and added an algorithm.. Could you take a look at it? And could you maybe explain me why the time complexity of Positions() is equal to $O(\log n)$ ? @GerryMyerson

Comment: Welcome back, evinda. If it's a question about coding, I'm sorry, I can't answer it; but there's a coding site for that. As to why it's $O(\log n)$, I thought I explained that. Suppose $n$ is between $2^r$ and $2^{r+1}$. You ask $r+1$ questions until you get a "no"; then you ask $r$ questions in a binary search on the interval between $2^r$ and $2^{r+1}$. So all told, you ask (roughly) $2r$ questions, where $r$ is (roughly) $\log_2n$, which is a constant multiple of $\log n$.

Comment: So are we OK now, evinda?

Comment: @evinda: Your while loop is asking a constant K amount of questions to find the range to implement the binary search. There looks to be two coding implementation errors at first glance. namely, pos=2*i would give you 2,4,6,10,12,14.. you want the sequence to go 2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,... i.e. powers of two. Also I didn't see 'i' declared anywhere?? and where is i incrementing in the while loop? what you want is something like, pos= i**2, where 'i' is you iterative step, literally how many times you've asked. ** may or may not be supported by your compiler, but its intend is expnt

Comment: @evinda: Since in the while loop after its fixed up, you ask a K amt of times then the range is found. so, K + (binary search), but hear is the thing: Binary search is guaranteed to have log(n) results (because you are dividing the problem space in half each step therefore its logarithmic e.g. log of base two of n). Now you do the Big O analysis- the code will discriminate against any additive constant or multiplicative constant, they are factored away, because we are representing an asymptotic characteristic of the algorithm, constant factors and additives are negligible and can be ignored.